# document.getElementById().onClick() not firing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have webpack on a vanilla HTML5 page in my Rails app.

I've got the `onClick` handler defined in Webpack with:

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
  document.getElementById('add-card').onClick = () => {
    $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
  }
});
```

The button renders on the page as:

```
<a class="ui button" id="add-card">Click me</a>
```

Clicking it does nothing. However, within the console, I can see that the handler is defined:

```
document.getElementById('add-card').onClick
ƒ () {
    $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
  }
```

And when I execute it with `document.getElementById('add-card').onClick()`, it works perfectly!

How do I get my onClick handler to fire when the element is clicked?

Edit: For the picky observers, I have jQuery installed and configured properly through Webpack.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and vanilla JS?

Comment: onclick, not onClick

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(document).ready()=> {  on that first line there? looks like you got a syntax error with that extra "("

Comment: @Rexa nope, `.ready()` accepts a callback. See: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @amingilani Ah, oops! I get it now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing vanilla js and jquery.  You can either do

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
    document.getElementById('add-card').addEventListener('click', () => {
        $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
    })
});
```

or you can do

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
    $('#add-card').on('click', () => {
        $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

When you do `document.getElementById('add-card')` you get back a Node, not a jQuery object, so there is no onClick (although there is onclick, but it's better to use addEventListener). If you do `$('#add-card')` you get back a jQuery object, so you can use jQuery methods on it.

Comment: OP did mention this to be a rails app, note. JQuery requires an import, the library files themselves or a cdn. Webpack will not install jQuery for unless you tell it to do so.

Comment: Wait, that works. Why is that a problem, though? I always thought of jQuery as syntactic sugar over vanilla JS.

Comment: It is, but when you do `document.getElementById('add-card')` you get back a `Node`, not a jQuery object, so there is no `onClick` (although there is `onclick`, but it's better to use `addEventListener`).  If you do `$('#add-card')` you get back a jQuery object, so you can use jQuery methods on it.

Comment: which is to say, it's not a problem to mix them, but you just have to be aware of when you have which type of object.

Comment: That expains it perfectly. Can you please just move this `onClick` vs `onclick` for jQuery vs Vanilla JS explanation to the body, and I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `onClick` by `onclick`:

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
  document.getElementById('add-card').onclick = () => {
    $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't encourage his use of jQuery in this context. He doesn't even have it installed, or tagged in the question

Comment: @Callat Uh, what?

Comment: @Callat I do have jQuery installed. Thanks answerer, this has to be the dumbest mistake I've made in a long time.